# Looking for more details about "Group varint encoding/decoding" presented in Jeff's slides

Tags: algorithm, search, compression, integer

I noticed that in Jeff's slides "Challenges in Building Large-Scale Information Retrieval Systems", which can also be downloaded here: http://research.google.com/people/jeff/WSDM09-keynote.pdf, a method of integers compression called "group varint encoding" was mentioned. It was said much faster than 7 bits per byte integer encoding (2X more). I am very interested in this and looking for an implementation of this, or any more details that could help me implement this by myself.

I am not a pro and new to this, and any help is welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's referring to "variable integer encoding", where the number of bits used to store an integer when serialized is not fixed at 4 bytes.  There is a good description of [varint in the protocol buffer documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/encoding.html#varints).

It is used in encoding [Google's protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/), and you can browse the [protocol buffer source code](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#WTeibokF6gE/trunk/src/google/protobuf/wire_format.h&q=varint%20package:http://protobuf%5C.googlecode%5C.com&d=4).

The `CodedOutputStream` contains the exact encoding function [WriteVarint32FallbackToArrayInline](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#WTeibokF6gE/trunk/src/google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.cc&q=varint%20package:http://protobuf%5C.googlecode%5C.com&d=4&l=632):

```
inline uint8* CodedOutputStream::WriteVarint32FallbackToArrayInline(
    uint32 value, uint8* target) {
  target[0] = static_cast<uint8>(value | 0x80);
  if (value >= (1 << 7)) {
    target[1] = static_cast<uint8>((value >>  7) | 0x80);
    if (value >= (1 << 14)) {
      target[2] = static_cast<uint8>((value >> 14) | 0x80);
      if (value >= (1 << 21)) {
        target[3] = static_cast<uint8>((value >> 21) | 0x80);
        if (value >= (1 << 28)) {
          target[4] = static_cast<uint8>(value >> 28);
          return target + 5;
        } else {
          target[3] &= 0x7F;
          return target + 4;
        }
      } else {
        target[2] &= 0x7F;
        return target + 3;
      }
    } else {
      target[1] &= 0x7F;
      return target + 2;
    }
  } else {
    target[0] &= 0x7F;
    return target + 1;
  }
}
```

The cascading `if`s will only add additional bytes onto the end of the `target` array if the magnitude of `value` warrants those extra bytes.  The `0x80` masks the byte being written, and the `value` is shifted down.  From what I can tell, the `0x7f` mask causes it to signify the "last byte of encoding".  (When OR'ing `0x80`, the highest bit will always be `1`, then the last byte clears the highest bit (by AND'ing `0x7f`).  So, when reading varints you read until you get a byte with a zero in the highest bit.

I just realized you asked about "Group VarInt encoding" specifically.  Sorry, that code was about basic VarInt encoding (still faster than 7-bit).  The basic idea looks to be similar.  Unfortunately, it's *not* what's being used to store 64bit numbers in protocol buffers.  I wouldn't be surprised if that code was open sourced somewhere though.

Using the ideas from `varint` and the diagrams of "Group varint" from the slides, it shouldn't be too too hard to cook up your own :)

Here is another page describing [Group VarInt compression](http://www.ir.uwaterloo.ca/book/addenda-06-index-compression.html), which contains decoding code.  Unfortunately they allude to publicly available implementations, but they don't provide references.

```
void DecodeGroupVarInt(const byte* compressed, int size, uint32_t* uncompressed) {
  const uint32_t MASK[4] = { 0xFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFF };
  const byte* limit = compressed + size;
  uint32_t current_value = 0;
  while (compressed != limit) {
    const uint32_t selector = *compressed++;
    const uint32_t selector1 = (selector & 3);
    current_value += *((uint32_t*)(compressed)) & MASK[selector1];
    *uncompressed++ = current_value;
    compressed += selector1 + 1;
    const uint32_t selector2 = ((selector >> 2) & 3);
    current_value += *((uint32_t*)(compressed)) & MASK[selector2];
    *uncompressed++ = current_value;
    compressed += selector2 + 1;
    const uint32_t selector3 = ((selector >> 4) & 3);
    current_value += *((uint32_t*)(compressed)) & MASK[selector3];
    *uncompressed++ = current_value;
    compressed += selector3 + 1;
    const uint32_t selector4 = (selector >> 6);
    current_value += *((uint32_t*)(compressed)) & MASK[selector4];
    *uncompressed++ = current_value;
    compressed += selector4 + 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Updated. By the way, good find on the presentation, I'll check that out later. :)

Comment: You are quick and I will check that soon :)

Comment: Unfortunately, after closer inspection, that 64 bit encoding code wasn't for "group varint".  It was just a more complex encoder for varint.  I'll poke around tomorrow to find `group varint` code, it's too late tonight :)

Comment: However!  I found a (non-google) implementation for decoding.  Updated... now good night for real.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing and found this GitHub project in Java:
https://github.com/stuhood/gvi/
Looks promising !

Comment: It has a little bug when having group + 2 elements, I posted a fix in the Issues section there. Otherwise, its very fast and efficient! I usually experience 65-70% compression even on a small number of bits (my data is sequential, and delta encoded to store only the differences between each number, perfect input for group var int)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of decoding with bitmask, in c/c++ you could use predefined structures that corresponds to the value in the first byte.. complete example that uses this: http://www.oschina.net/code/snippet_12_5083

Answer (score 1):

Another Java implementation for groupvarint: https://github.com/catenamatteo/groupvarint 
But I suspect the very large switch has some drawback in Java