# What is a good representation for a searchable bit matrix with fixed number of columns?

Tags: database, algorithm, search, database-design, data-structures

The raw data can be described as a fixed number of columns (on the order of a few thousand) and a large (on the order of billions) and variable number of rows. Each cell is a bit. The desired query would be something like *find all rows where bits 12,329,2912,3020 are set*. Something like

```
for (i=0;i< max_ents;i++) 
    if (entry[i].data & mask == mask) 
        add_result(i);
```

In a typical case not many (e.g. 5%) bits are set in any particular row, but that's not guaranteed, there's a degree of variability.

On a higher level the data describes a bitwise fingerprint of entries and the data itself is a kind of search index so maximal speed is desired. What algorithm would be good for this kind of search? At the moment I'm thinking of having separate sparse (packed/compressed) bit vectors for each column separately. I doubt it's optimal though.

Comment: Are there common patterns to your searches?  If some columns are queried more often than others, it might make sense to make them indexed `BINARY(1)` or `BINARY(2)` columns, and leave the rest in a `BINARY(300)` (or whatever it takes).

Comment: There is a pattern to the data and a pattern to the queries but it can't be determined ahead of time. The query pattern can be established statistically. The data pattern might be a bit more difficult.

Comment: You say that in a typical case, not many (e.g. 5%) bits are set in any particular row. If the same could be said for columns, it might be worth trying to store for each column a set of row indices where the bits are set in that particular column. Intersecting these sets is likely to be fast, in the random case at least: if each one set is about 0.05 of the whole amount of rows, an intersection of two such random sets is only about (0.05)-squared of the total size, and so on.

Comment: The number of bits in a particular column could potentially be large. Some columns would be very very sparse where as others would be rather dense. For simplicity think of each bit as "indexed_data[row] contains information[column]". If I understand your suggestion though, I think I can do the same with a set of bit vectors, can't I?

Answer (score 2):

This looks similar to "text search", in particular to that of intersecting reverse indexes. Let me go through the simplest algorithm for doing that.

First, you should create sorted lists of numbers where each bit is set. E.g., for the table of numbers:

Row 1 -> 10110

Row 2 -> 00111

Row 3 -> 11110

Row 4 -> 00011

Row 5 -> 01010

Row 6 -> 10101

you can create an reverse index:

Bit 0 is set in -> 2, 4, 6

Bit 1 is set in -> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Bit 2 is set in -> 1, 2, 3, 6

etc.

Now, for a query (let's say bits 0 & 1 & 2), you just have to merge these sorted lists using a merge sort like algorithm,. To do this, you can do it by first merging lists 0, 1, giving you {2, 4}, and then merge this with list 2 giving you {2}.

Several optimizations are possible, including, but not limited to, compressing these lists, since the difference between consecutive items is typically small, doing more efficient merging etc.

But, to save more hassle, why not reuse work that others have already done? ;)... You can readily use (should be possible in less than 1 day of coding) any open source text search engine (I suggest [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/)) to perform this task, and it should contain several optimizations which people have built over a long time ;). (Hint: You should treat each row as a "doc" in text search parlance, and each bit as a "token").

**Edit** (adding some of the algorithms by request of the question author):

a) **Compression**: One of the most effective things you can do is compression of postings lists (the sorted list corresponding to each position). Most algorithms generally take differences of consecutive terms, and then compress them according to some encoding ([Gamma Coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elias_gamma_coding), [Varint Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982957/looking-for-more-details-about-group-varint-encoding-decoding-presented-in-jef)) to name a few. This compresses the inverted list so that it either consumes less file space (thus less file I/O), or uses less memory for encoding the same set of numbers. In your case, I can estimate that each posting list will contain ~ 5% * 1e9 = 5e7 elements. If they are uniformly distributed across 0 - 1e9, the gaps should be around 20, and so let us say encoding each gap takes ~ 8b on an average (this is a large overestimation), adding up to 500MB. So for 1000 lists you will need 500GB of space, which definitely needs a disk space. This in turn means that you should go for as good a compression algorithm as possible, since a better compression means less file I/O and you are going to be I/O bound.

b) **Intersection Order**: You should always intersect lists starting from the smallest, since that is guaranteed to create the smallest sized intermediate lists, which means less comparisons later, by techniques shown below.

c) **Merge algorithm**: Since your index almost certainly spills to disk, there is probably not much you can do at an algorithmic level. But some of the ideas that are used is to use a binary search based procedure for merging two lists instead of the straightforward linear merge procedure in case one of the lists is much smaller than the other (this will lead to `O(N*log(M))` complexity instead of `O(N+M)` where `M >> N`). But for file based indices this is almost never a good idea since binary search makes many random accesses, which can completely screw up your disk latency, whereas the linear merge procedure is strictly sequential.

d) **[Skip Lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list)**: This is another great data structure used to store sorted postings lists, which can also then support efficient "binary search" mentioned before. The key idea here is that the upper levels of the skip list can be kept in memory, and this can greatly speed up the last stages of your intersection algorithm, when you can simply search through the in-memory upper levels to get to a disk offset, and then do disk access from there. There is a point when binary search + skiplist based merge becomes more efficient than linear merge and can be found by experimentation.

e) **Caching**: No-brainer. If some of your terms occur frequently, cache them in-memory so that you can get them more efficiently in the future. Note that the cache can also be, e.g. a faster flash based disk, which can give you better throughput as well as probably cache a significant number of the more frequent terms (a 32GB memory can only hold ~ 64 of these lists, whereas a 256GB flash disk can hold ~ 512).

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but your answer merely restates my question. Can you provide details of the optimizations you briefly mention? .... and using an off the shelf components or products won't do (for reasons that aren't directly related to the original question).

Comment: Ok. added some frequently used algorithms.

Comment: Thank you, but, still but. :-) anyway, there are answers in there so +1, but... the inverted index can go to 120MB per column, uncompressed (one bit per entry), with some compression I'd say about 40MB hands down (without sacrificing fast queries). That's why I mentioned sparse bit vectors. I was interested in improvements over that. e.g. can you get the data for the whole set for 1K columns and 1B rows to much less than 16GB? I think it's quite doable. I want to know if there's anything better than bit vectors per columns.

Comment: This is a good answer.  You can only do better than compression of individual columns if there are some subsets of columns that are highly correlated -- but I suspect that's not the case here (or at least you wouldn't want it to be the case), because highly correlated columns are not as useful for fingerprints.  (If when column i=0, column j=0 99% of the time, and when column i=1, column j=1 99% of the time, you would probably throw away one of these columns to get a smaller fingerprint that is very nearly as good.)

Comment: @j_random_hacker well, in my case the fingerprint hash based ("some" "guarantee" of non-correlation). But as I'm pondering this, I was thinking I might permute the matrix using some matrix seriation algorithm, BUT 1) updates could suffer 2) I didn't find a seriation algorithm yet 3) my intuition is that it would be SLOW. OTOH this way row correlations would compress better. I was also thinking of sorting the matrix in such a way as to maximize the zeroes on left or right, then sort the matrix according to the zero count, this would take nearly no space and limit the result to a range.